# Is qua an adverb or adjective?

Tags: adjective, adverb

Keller's Learn to Read Latin says

> quare (rel. or interrog. adv.) because of which thing; therefore; why
>
> The qua of the adverb quare may be either a relative adjective (see
> $86) -- "because of which thing," "therefore," -- or an interrogative
> adjective (see $88), "because of which thing," "why." Quare was
> originally an Ablative of Cause. Quare may be written as two words
> (qua re).

[image]
[image]

Does it mean that qua is the adjective corresponding to adverb quare?

Whose meanings do "because of which thing," "therefore" and "because of which thing," "why" belong to,

- qua or
- quare?

The Oxford Latin Dictionary only lists qua as interr., rel., or indefinite adv. [abl. sg. f. of qui^1]. So is qua an adj.?

[image]

Comment: The point is just that you can spell it either *quare* or *qua re* (but not *quire*), and the second spelling as the ablative of *quae res* should make the original meaning clearer.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I was asking about qua in quare, as mentioned in the quote

Comment: Do you have a physical copy? I think you might have some typos.

Comment: @cmw I have a scanned copy, which is clear to me. If I could access Google Books, I would verify that there. If you suspect there is a typo, please point it out.

Comment: If you are wondering why this question scores so badly, I'll offer my thoughts. First, try to avoid using pictures, especially pictures of text. Instead, please insert the text as text. If there is too much text to transcribe, then you probably have too much text and should cut it down. Second, make sure your transcription is correct. Don't rely on OCR but actually read the text yourself and type it in. In this question the OCR mistook *quare* for *quire*, but you should have been able to fix that error.

Comment: Third, if you get a useful answer, please accept it usng the little check mark. You have never done it despite asking several questions, and that comes across as ungrateful. Fourth, please keep an open mind. For example, it makes sense to see an ablative or accusative form of a pronoun as an adverb. Trying to make a clear distinction been pronouns and adjectives and adverbs isn't very useful. I encourage you to postpone questions of fine distinctions until you have learned to actually read and write Latin with some fluency.

Comment: Fifth, if you have restrictions like not having access to Google services or anything blocked in China, please state so. It can be frustrating to offer you help and then hear that you can't accept it because of such limitations. Sixth, if you need help with asking questions that are received better by the community, consider asking for help on our [meta site](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta thanks. if you don't mind me pointing out, the third and fourth equally apply outside question askers. It has become my personal choice to not to accept a reply easily, but to upvote it almost always. It has nothing to do with not being grateful as you described. I am more used to downvotes than you may probably think.

Answer (score 4):

It's *quare*, not *quire*. The line over the a is a macron: ā.

What your textbook is saying is that *quare* is functionally an adverb. It was once two words, the relative (or perhaps interrogative) adjective *qua* ("because of which") plus the noun *re* ("thing") (both in the ablative), but now it's fossilized as a single unit. You need both together to get "wherefore."

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the typo quire. I meant to type quare. My question still holds. Is qua an adv or adj?

Comment: @Tim I answered that. It *was* an adjective. It's now, together with *re*, functionally an adverb. But it's a single unit now.

Comment: Thanks.  (1) The Oxford Latin Dictionary lists qua as an interr., rel., or indefinite **adv.** [abl. sg. f. of qui^1] , and also lists qui^1 as an interr., rel., or indefinite **adj.**. How can qua, as qui's abl. sg. f., an interr., rel., or indefinite **adv.** but not an interr., rel., or indefinite **adj.**?  (2) In the meanings of qui^1 listed in the Oxford  Latin Dictionary, which one does qua ("because of which ") come from? I can provide the screenshots of the meanings of qui^1 (in three pages), if you don't have access to it.

Comment: @Tim *qui* is just a relative pronoun, that's all! "because of which" is not its meaning, it's an attempt to capture its grammatical function in English, in this particular context (*quare*). In a different context it might mean "than which" or just "which" (e.g. *qua in re qua arte usus sit, memorabile est* -- random Google Books hit). There are countless possibilities, because the ablative is so versatile.

Comment: We meet the same grammatical function (whichever it is) in *ea re* or *quibus rebus*, so there is no point in looking up *qua* in the dictionary. Just skip ahead to the point where your book treats of relative clauses, and everything will become clear.